# How do I test if my Mamiya RZ67 is working?

Tags: medium-format

I have acquired a second hand Mamiya RZ67 Professional (Not 2) body for very cheap. to clarify it is just the body with no focusing screen, no film back, no viewfinder, no lens. I did put a new battery in when I got it.

The only gear similarly available at the time of purchase were RBs at the course I was studying. My lecturer, very experienced with all sorts of gear, couldn't get it going with the RB gear. He then told me try RZ backs and viewfinder to test. Unfortunately I still haven't found any.

I can prep the camera by cocking the lever down, but the only thing that happens when I push the shutter is the orange right hand light in the view finder turns on, in either normal mode or multiple exposure mode. And yes I have the shutter collar in the right position.

My question is, will the mirror move without the back and viewfinder? If so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is probably the dark slide interlock working normally -- it's there to prevent you from accidentally trying to take pictures with the film back's dark slide in place. It's been a while since I've been hands-on with an RZ (and it was a II when I did), but it should just be a matter or shorting a pair of contacts (sorry, can't tell you which ones). There are PDF manuals [available online](http://www.butkus.org/chinon/mamiya/mamiya_rz67/mamiya_rz67.htm). If you're not comfortable shorting contacts, then you'll need a functioning back to test the system.